# Can I have two apps running split screen on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, screen, multitasking

Is there any way and have there been any examples of split-screening two apps on iPad so, for example, I can be scrolling through a PDF or PPT and simultaneously be typing notes about it in a text editor with an external keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to have one app that does both the displaying and input, and I know of no apps like that.

There is no provision for split-screening apps, even iPhone apps. The best you'll be able to do is fast app switching.

Comment: Using gestures if you are using an iPad 2 might shave a few seconds off each switch, but you are still required to switch.  I had high hopes of running iphone apps native side by side on an ipad, but it never happened, and never will.

Comment: @stuffe "never will" ;)

Comment: @grgarside Hehe, I'm gonna stand by this one, technically you still can't run 2 iphone apps side by side, only 2 iPad apps with dynamic layout ;) (and you can only type into the active window, which if you are mega pedantic isn't what the OP wanted!) :P

Comment: On a serious note, this is why all questions should be tagged with OS version

Answer (score 1):

You can use iOS 9's Split View.

> With Split View, you can open and use two apps at the same time. Open an app, then tap or drag the app divider to start using both apps. Slide down from the top of the screen to change the app on the right. If you want to close one of the apps, slide the divider over the app that you want to close.
>
> [image]

This requires iPad Pro, iPad Air 2, or iPad mini 4. For more information, see:

- [About Multitasking on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202070)